# Don't delete some rows from UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to implement the functionality to delete some rows from a `table view` and not others. In this case, everything in `section 0` should not be deletable (so not swipe to delete either), but everything in `section 1` should be able to. How can I implement this? Currently `section 0` rows cannot delete, but when the user swipes, the delete action still appears.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if (indexPath.section == 0){
        // dont delete the rows

    } else {
        if (editingStyle == .delete){
            let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Conversions> = Conversions.fetchRequest()
            do {
                let result = try PersistenceService.context.fetch(fetchRequest)

                // Delete from CoreData and remove from the array
                if (result.contains(allConversions[indexPath.row])){
                    PersistenceService.context.delete(allConversions[indexPath.row])
                    allConversions = allConversions.filter { $0 != allConversions[indexPath.row] }
                    PersistenceService.saveContext()
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITableView` has a method exactly for this purpose called `canEditRowAt`. You just need to return false when indexPath.section == 0

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool { 
    return indexPath.section != 0 
}
```

Comment: @Nouman not related to your question but RangeReplaceableCollection has a mutating method called `removeAll(where:)` that you can use instead of filter `allConversions.removeAll { $0 == allConversions[indexPath.row] }`